# Remove " " from a csv using apache nifi

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have a csv looks like this :

```
id,name,age
"1","sachith","29"
"2","nalaka","29"
```

I want this to be like :

```
id,name,age
1,sachith,29
2,nalaka,29
```

For this I have used : `ReplaceText` Processor.

In it I have following settings:

Search value : `(?s)(^.*$)`

Replacement value : `${'$1:replaceAll('\"$1\"',$1)'}`

Replacement Strategy : Regex Replace

Evaluation Mode : Entire text

But output file doent have any proper value. I think I am missing the right regular expression for `Replacement Strategy`.

Or do I have to use a separate processor for this task?

Comment: the simplest search value (regexp) = `"` and the replacement just empty value.

Comment: @daggett yes, this is the answer, Can you please post this as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Also make sure the fields do not contain any separators before removing the quotes.

Comment: @Danny_ds what kind of separators do you mean?

Comment: @Sachith Field separators, like the comma in this case. If those appear in the fields, those fields have to be enclosed by double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want just remove all double quotes the simplest solution:

- search value (regexp) = `"`
- and the replacement just empty value